# Prevent SIGINT from reaching child processes

Tags: bash, process, signals, trap

I have a bash script for running a server, which will typically be terminated by the user using `Ctrl-C`. On exit it runs a cleanup function, which I don't want to be interrupted by a second `Ctrl-C`.

```
#!/bin/bash

...

function cleanup {
    trap '' INT
    echo -n " Cleaning up..."
    scp $SRV:~/$DIR/server.log . && ssh -t $SRV "rm -rf ~/$DIR"
    echo " Finished."

    exit 0
}
trap cleanup EXIT

...
```

At the moment, a second `Ctrl-C` before the `scp` has finished causes the script to hang indefinitely. I understand this has something to do with the `SIGINT` being sent both to the bash script and the `scp` process, but I am at a loss as to why this causes the script to hang, rather than just causing cleanup to fail.

So my question is:

1. Why does this cause the script to hang?
2. How can I prevent the SIGINT from reaching the `scp` and `ssh` child processes?

Comment: Execution never reaches the end of the `scp ...` line - the script hangs before `echo` is called. And when I `set -x` to show which commands are called, I can see that the `&& ssh ...` part is never called either.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`trap '' INT` is meant to ignore SIGINTs for the shell and all its children.

But looking at `strace` outputs on `scp`, it looks like `scp` installs its own SIGINT handler which cancels the SIG_IGN above.

The only way to prevent it from getting the SIGINT would be to run it in a different process group like with:

```
perl -MPOSIX -e 'setpgid 0,0; exec @ARGV' scp...
```

or

```
(set -m; scp ... & wait)
```

or tell the tty driver to stop sending SIGINT upon Ctrl-C (like with `stty -isig`, or `stty intr ''` for `^C` alone), though you'd want to restore the settings afterwards:

```
saved=$(stty -g)
stty intr ''
scp ...
stty "$saved"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Running in a separate process group works for me. Still no idea why it was hanging (as opposed to just exiting without finishing the `scp`) but that was only to satisfy my curiosity :-)